# Is there any differences between Gnome-Global menu and Appmenu-indicator?

Tags: appmenu, globalmenu

I'm wondering that is there any differences between Gnome-Global menu and Appmenu-indicator? Or are they just only one? Which one is still being developed?

Comment: Functions the same, maybe a few differences on some features. However, indicator-appmenu is a differnt package from gnome2-globalmenu AFAIK.

Answer (score 5):

Global menu is old and I don't think it is being actively developed anymore.

Application Menu is under very active development by the Ubuntu community and Canonical employees.

Application Menu supports way more apps than the old global menu.

Comment: Gnome Global Menu isn't necessarily dead... yet. It has had releases as recently as July. It even has a Gnome 3 re-write. App Menu is definitely the "wave of the future" though.

Answer (score 4):

appmenu-indicator is designed to be a desktop agnostic way to provide for a "global menu" from GNOME, GTK, and QT applications.

gnome-global-menu is GNOME/GTK specific.

That is just the surface. Programatically, there are several underlying fundamental differences.

The loose description of each might seem the same but I would focus on appmenu-indicator in Ubuntu for the best integration of all "Ubuntu provided" software.